# How to configure mat-stepper to only allow going to the last step if FormGroup of all previous steps are valid?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12, mat-stepper

I am using a mat-stepper for a dialog that is used both for creating new and for editing existing entities of a specific type. The stepper consists of four steps. Each of the first three steps contain a form for entering data while the last step is only a summary/overview of the data which was entered via the first three steps.

I only want to allow the user to go to the last step if he/she entered valid data in all three steps. To do this, I added the `linear` attribute to the stepper to force the user to go through each step. This works perfectly fine when the user is creating a new entity via the dialog. However, when editing an existing entity, it is not possible to for example go directly to step 3 before at least clicking on step 2. When opening the dialog in editing mode, I programmatically fill all of the fields in the steps with the data of the existing entity, so I want to allow the user to go to any of the steps directly, as long as valid data is entered in the currently visible step. Here is a stackblitz showing the problem:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rydsnd)

Despite all fields being already filled programmatically, I cannot for example directly go to step 3 or 4 before clicking on the previous steps.

My first attempt to resolve this was to remove the `linear` attribute when the dialog is opened in editing mode. While this has the desired effect, it also allows the user to clear some of the fields in a step and then directly go to the last step, which I do not want to allow because the last step should only be reachable if all previous steps are completely filled with valid data.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour in a mat-stepper? If my problem isn't clear, please let me know and I will try my best to describe it in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be easier to answer if you included some code, or better yet, a stack blitz. But in any case, can't you simply set the "linear" attribute programatically?, something like:

```
<mat-stepper [linear]="this.formGroup.valid" #stepper>
```

-- EDIT --

After you put up your stackblitz, my suggestion remains the same – the only issue is you have three separate forms. So just to make things easy I've made a globalForm that consists of the other three:

```
globalForm = new FormGroup({
  form1: this.form1,
  form2: this.form2,
  form3: this.form3
});
```

Then in the html I assign linear to !globalForm.valid

```
<mat-stepper [linear]="!globalForm.valid" #stepper>
```

Alternatively you could skip the global form and just use

```
<mat-stepper [linear]="!(form1.valid && form2.valid && form3.valid)" #stepper>
```

It comes down to preference I guess.

In any case, you'll see now that you can jump to the end at the start, but if you empty one of the fields, you cannot progress until you add a value to it.

Here is the fork:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2mb2b8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: This is exactly what I tried already but the problem is that neither the linear nor the non-linear stepper behave exactly like I want in editing mode of my dialog. I didn't have enough time to create a stack blitz when asking my question due to an appointment. I will try to create one later and update my question to make my problem more clear.

Comment: I just added a stackblitz to my question. Hopefully this makes the problem more clear.

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly!